# Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

[image: Help]

I have no idea how to work this question. Can someone offer some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the vector $\vec{x_{1}} = (1,0)$ being sent under $T$?  Where is $\vec{x_{2}} = (0,1)$ being sent?

Do you know why the answers to the above questions basically gives you the answer to the problem?

---

**Update**

Recall that every linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^{n} \to \Bbb R^{m}$ has an associated matrix $A_{m \times n}$ such that for any $\vec{x}$, $T(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$.  So, we can characterize any linear transformation $T$ by a matrix $M$ such that, to figure out what happens to $\vec{x}$ under $T$, we could just multiply out $A \vec{x}$.

Now, also recall that if $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which it is in your example, then multiplying $A$ with the vector $(1,0)$ gives you the first column of $A$.  Multiplying $A$ by $(0,1)$ gives you the second column of $A$.  So, to figure out the two columns of $A$, since $T(1,0)$ is the same thing as $A$ times $(1,0)$, then computing $T(1,0)$ should give you the first column of $A$.  Similarly, $T(0,1)$ should give you the second column of $A$.

Comment: Do I take $(1,0)$ and do those operations to it and then also to $(0,1)$? Is  $x2→=(1,0)$ considered $(x1, x2)$?

Comment: @Torched90 I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, but where it says that the x vector in the question is equal to (x1, x2), what do those represent? Do i just carry out the operations with the variables or do I put in a value?

Comment: @Torched90 They are just saying $x$ is a vector with two components.  By saying $x = (x_{1}, x_{2})$, they are just saying $x$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^{2}$.  There, they are just defining what the map $T$ does to any vector $x \in \Bbb R^{2}$.  Now, figure out what it does specifically to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and, as is said in my answer, you should be able to put those together to get your matrix $A$.

Comment: Okay, so I got an answer of $(-3/5, -4/5)$ Does that seem to be right?

Comment: @Torched90 You're on the right track, but your answer should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  Reread my answer and all of my comments.

Comment: Oh, so then it would be [(-3/5, -4/5), (-4/5, -3/5)]

Comment: @Torched90 That's what I got, except the last entry in the second column should be positive $3/5$.  Also, to check your answer, take a random vector, like $x = (4, 7)$, and first plug it into $T$ and compute the result.  Then do $A$ times $(4,7)$ (where $A$ is the matrix you found).  Do you get the same result when you do these two things?  You should if your answer is right.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.